# List only regular files

Tags: ls, inode

I desire to list all inodes in current directory that are **regular files** (i.e. not directories, links, or special files), with `ls -la` (`ll`).

I went to the `man ls` searching for `type` and found only this which I didn't quite understand in that regard:

> --indicator-style=WORD
>
> append indicator with style WORD to entry names: none (default), slash
>   (-p),  file-type  (--file-type),
>                 classify (-F)

How could I list only regular files with `ls -la` (`ll` as my shortcut in Ubuntu 18.04)?

Comment: Can you try this `ls -la | grep "^-"`. Atleast that worked for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -ls
```

This would give you the regular files in the current directory in a format similar to what you would get with `ls -lisa` (but only showing regular files, thanks to `-type -f` on the command line).

Note that `-ls` (introduced by BSDs) and `-maxdepth` (introduced by GNU `find`) are non-standard (though now common) extensions. POSIXly, you can write it:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -exec ls -ldi {} +
```

(which also has the benefit of sorting the file list, though possibly in big independent chunks if there's a large number of files in the current directory).

Answer (score 8):

`ls` doesn’t have an option to do this, and you shouldn’t parse its output to filter regular files.

[`find` can be used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480041/86440) to find and list regular files instead of `ls`. Another option is to use Zsh and its [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
ls -l -- *(D.)
```

lists all regular files, including those whose name starts with a dot.

Answer (score 2):

Well when you use -a is shows everything that is hidden; hidden files and folders. Instead of ls, you'll probably want to use the find command instead. This should help you get started:

```
find -type f -exec ls -la {} \;
```

You'll need to change to the directory you want to search first.

Comment: You probably should use `-maxdepth 1` to stop the `find` descending into subdirectories.